# Set range using a variable for the row - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Short and (hopefully) simple question, I have searched a worksheet range to find a particular reference number and then want to search a range in that row for the first blank cell from the left, using the code snippet below (which I developed from this question: [mrExcel help site](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/588468-excel-visual-basic-applications-how-define-column-range-variable.html))

```
Set projectSearchRange = Sheets("Milestones").Range("A:A").Find(projectref, , xlValues, xlWhole)

current_row = projectSearchRange.Row

Set searchrange = Sheets("Milestones").Range(Sheets("Milestones").Cells(current_row, 2), _
Sheets("Milestones").Cells(current_row, 23)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1).Activate

milestoneduedate = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Value
```

However, the `Set Searchrange` line is throwing a

> Runtime 424 - object required error

but as I understand it, I have written the line correctly.

Any insight as to what I've done wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to declare the parent of ALL the range objects including the `Cells(` : `Set searchrange = Sheets("Milestones").Range(Sheets("Milestones").Cells(current_row, 2), Sheets("Milestones").Cells(current_row, 23)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1).Activate`

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks for that, but unfortunately its still throwing the exact same error.

Comment: What is the value of Current_row when it errors?

Comment: @ScottCraner 3. I'm wondering whether the "cells(1)" at the end before the .Activate is triggering it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Function MilestoneDueDate() As Variant

Dim projectSearchRange As Range
Dim Current_Row As Long
Dim SearchRange As Range

With Sheets("Milestones")
    Set projectSearchRange = .Range("A:A").Find(projectref, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    Current_Row = projectSearchRange.Row
    Set SearchRange = .Range(Cells(Current_Row, 2), Cells(Current_Row, 23)) _
       .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1)
End With

MilestoneDueDate = SearchRange.Offset(0, 1).Value

End Function
```

Comment: well that removed the 424 error, now its causing an application-defined or object defined error at the "set searchrange" line.

Comment: That is likely caused by there not being any blank cell in the range you define. Column 23 is hard-coded. Change the end column to, say, 100. That should find an empty cell.